# How does SSL work in Windows Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Previously i have asked question to choose service from windows azure which is best suitable for my application and based on answer @ [Can we run windowservice or EXE in Azure website or in Virtual Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384917/can-we-run-windowservice-or-exe-in-azure-website-or-in-virtual-machine) I am going to use **Virtual Machine**

Regarding WAVM i have below queries

1)Can i implement SSL in same manner as we can do in dedicated server through IIS settings?

2)Also for stroing files/image  i am not going to use storage account, so would be there any issue regarding this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SSL the same way as on any Windows server. Dont forget to add the endpoints for internet (80) and SSL (443). The best way is to have the same port numbers externaly.

[image: Endpoints for ssl website on Azure VM]

I have used this in a training for WIF where the Domain controler and ADFS were on a virtual machine in Azure.

For the second awnser. the C:\drive (OS disk) has a differnt backup senario than the disks you ad to the VM. So for storage of data add a Datadisk to your VM. The disk have a max size of 999GB. Depending on the VM size you can mout up to 16 disks. See image for instructions

[image: creating a datadisd for Azure VM]

The vhd file for the disk is in Azurestorage and therfore replictated 3 times localy and 3 times due to georeplication.

S.Y.

Michiel van Buuren

Comment: So it seems that data would be store on Storage account however i don't think any need to change the development accordingly as we need to do for cloud service?!