# Headless browsers and Windows Azure Websites

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless-browser

I´m trying to use a headless browser for  crawling purposes to add SEO features in a open source project  i´m developing.

The project sample site is deployed via Azure Websites.

I tried several ways to get the task working using different solutions like Selenium .NET (PhantomJSDriver, HTMLUnitDriver, ...) or even standalone PhantomJs .exe file.

I´m using a headless browser because the site  is based in DurandalJS, so it needs to execute scripts and wait for a condition to be true in order to return the generated HTML. For this reason, can´t use things like WebClient/WebResponse classes or HTMLAgilityPack which use to work just fine for non-javascript sites.

All the above methods works in my devbox localhost environment but the problem comes when uploading the site to Azure Websites. When using standalone phantomjs the site freezes when accessing the url endpoint and after a while return a HTTP 502 error. In case of using Selenium Webdriver i´m getting a

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:XXXX
```

I think the problem is with running .exe files in Azure and not with the code. I know it´s possible to run .exe files in Azure CloudServices via WebRole/WebWorkers but need to stay in Azure Websites for keep things simple.

It´s possible to run a headless browser in Azure Websites? Anyone have experience with this type of situation?

My code for the standalone PhantomJS solution is

```
//ASP MVC ActionResult

public ActionResult GetHTML(string url)
{
    string appRoot = Server.MapPath("~/");

    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1}", Path.Combine(appRoot, "Scripts\\seo\\renderHTML.js"), url),
        FileName = Path.Combine(appRoot, "bin\\phantomjs.exe"),
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    };
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = startInfo;
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    ViewData["result"] = output;
    return View();
}

// PhantomJS script

var resourceWait = 300,
    maxRenderWait = 10000;

var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    count = 0,
    forcedRenderTimeout,
    renderTimeout;

page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 1024 };

function doRender() {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
}

page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
    count += 1;
    //console.log('> ' + req.id + ' - ' + req.url);
    clearTimeout(renderTimeout);
};

page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
    if (!res.stage || res.stage === 'end') {
        count -= 1;
        //console.log(res.id + ' ' + res.status + ' - ' + res.url);
        if (count === 0) {
            renderTimeout = setTimeout(doRender, resourceWait);
        }
    }
};

page.open(system.args[1], function (status) {
    if (status !== "success") {
        //console.log('Unable to load url');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        forcedRenderTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            //console.log(count);
            doRender();
        }, maxRenderWait);
    }
});
```

and for the Selenium option

```
public ActionResult GetHTML(string url)
{
    using (IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver())
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            return d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#compositionComplete"));
        });

        var content = driver.PageSource;

        driver.Quit();

        return Content(content);
    }                      
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute exe files in the shared website environment, either you have to use the web services or you have to set up a proper (azure) virtual machine.

The free shared website service is really basic, and won't cut it when you need more advanced functionality.

See this question and accepted answer for a more elaborated answer: [Can we run windowservice or EXE in Azure website or in Virtual Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384917/can-we-run-windowservice-or-exe-in-azure-website-or-in-virtual-machine)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I guess that. Because i would like to stay in Azure Websites i´ll try to go with an online service running phantom like Blitline that seems to work just fine.

Comment: That answer is incorrect though. I've successfully used node on Azure Websites, as for PhantomJs - trying to get it working at the moment, current problem is that PhantomJs doesn't see the network names and without a set timeout the script won't stop

Comment: @DmitryDzygin Have you found a solution ? I experience same issue

Comment: @OakNinja I am able to execute ffmpeg.exe in Azure Standart Website but still headless browser fail.

Comment: @Freshblood somebody found out that the issue was related to PhantomJs using GDI components, and it is blocked on shared WAWS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900225/phantomjs-as-web-job-in-azure Judging from the response from Microsoft people - not likely going to be fixed any time soon.

Comment: @DmitryDzygin thanks for your response. I think that underlying issue is about chrome itself because even chrome driver does not work.  I have tried Firefox driver and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about shared and basic website environment but i am successfully run ffmpeg.exe from standart website environment. Despite that still phantomjs and even chromedriver itself is not working.
However i am able run Firefox driver successfully. In order to do that

I copied latest firefox directory from my local to website and below code worked well.

```
var binary = new FirefoxBinary("/websitefolder/blabla/firefox.exe");
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, new FirefoxProfile());
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I am getting "Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055" when running your code in a Azure Web Job. Any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't used it in Azure Web Job ... just try it in website environment.

Comment: Just tried it in a website environment. I get the error: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"