# Phantomjs renders black boxes on Azure Websites

Tags: azure, phantomjs, azure-web-app-service

Using latest [Phantomjs binaries v1.9.7](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows.zip) on Azure websites, it renders black boxes instead of character.

here is an example of simple phantomjs script on Azure:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.content = "Hello 123";
page.render("index.png");
phantom.exit(0);
```

the png and pdf result is [] [] [] [] [] [] [] in black
[image: black boxes from phantomsJS on Azure Websites]

And the jpg result is big black box

This prevent us from using phantomJS as a webjob and within websites

Note : phantomjs is working fine on VM,WebRole and WorkerRole

Comment: I think the question is related to my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900225/phantomjs-as-web-job-in-azure

Comment: Where is index.png file located? If its located within your site wwwroot, try specifying the full path like d:\home\site\wwwroot\index.png

Comment: the problem not in png location, the file is generated successfully but with black boxes as I mentioned. But I did what you said and the same problem is still there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PhantomJs uses `GDI+` APIs from Windows for creating fonts and vectors in PNGs and PDFs which is, unfortunately, not supported currently on Azure Websites