# Phantomjs in Azure Web Job

Tags: node.js, azure, phantomjs, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to create a web job in node on azure that will use phantomjs to get a rendered page and email it.

```
var phantom = require('node-phantom-simple');
phantom.create(function(err,ph) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
```

In the code above, the error is:

```
{
code: "ENOENT",
errno: "ENOENT",
syscall: "spawn"
}
```

Which means that phantom isn't working? Other stack questions indicate that phantom works on websites - nothing about web jobs. Would love a hand.

Comment: Created a more detailed issue on kudu github, https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1194

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS as web job in Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900225/phantomjs-as-web-job-in-azure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Webjobs actually works on same worker process for Azure websites
but PhantomJS will not work correctly on Azure websites nor azure webjobs because of GDI+ api is disabled on Azure websites , so you can't render images nor PDF using PhantomJS on Azure websites.

- you can use Azure WebRoles instead of Azure Website/Jobs
- If you are not rendring images/pdf using phantomsJS , you can use phantomjs on Azure websites/jobs

refs:

- [PhantomJS as web job in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900225/phantomjs-as-web-job-in-azure/22913653#22913653)
- [Phantomjs renders black boxes on Azure Websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965791/phantomjs-renders-black-boxes-on-azure-websites)