# Casperjs on Azure

Tags: javascript, azure, phantomjs, casperjs

Just tried to run a small CasperJS appplication on Azure. It hangs on the `casper.then()` statement, and program never ends.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({ verbose: true, logLevel: 'info' });

console.log(1)

casper.start();
casper.then(function () {
  console.log(3);
});
casper.run();

console.log(2);
```

Produces:

```
Kudo Remote Execution Console
Type 'exit' then hit 'enter' to get a new CMD process.
Type'cls' to clear the console

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\home>
D:\home\site>
D:\home\site\wwwroot>
D:\home\site\wwwroot\crawler>crawler.bat
1
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 1step
2
```

As you can see, `3` never gets printed out.

Comment: [PhantomJS uses GDI, which is disabled on Azure][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900225/phantomjs-as-web-job-in-azure

Answer (score 0):

You should add an error handler to the promise to see what's going on. There are usually two ways to do that (depending on the promise library. Either add a second function to the `then()` call or add a `.catch()` method call after it.
So use...

```
var casper = require('casper').create({ verbose: true, logLevel: 'info' });

console.log(1)

casper.start();
casper.then(
  function () {
    console.log(3);
  },
  function(err){
    //see what your err is here
  }
);
casper.run();

console.log(2);
```