# Communication between Azure Web Job and Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure, phantomjs

I am successfully running a Web Crawler on an Azure Web Job. To enable JavaScript rendering I need to pass the html source to PhantomJS and back to the Web Crawler. The problem is, that PhantomJS does not run on Azure Web Jobs. Therefore I need to run PhantomJS on a Worker Role.

How can I establish a quick communication between a Web Job and a Worker Role? I wanted to use the Azure Service Bus but there is a size limit of 256 KB per message.

Thanks

Comment: Combine a queue with a blob. Dump the content into a blob and notify the worker via a queue/bus.

Comment: Before I start: Do you have any experience how fast this is? The crawler will process multiple sites per second which needs to be rendered by the worker role.

Comment: If you want fast you'd be better off using some kind of socket and pushing the data directly IMHO.

Comment: how did you come to the conclusion that PhantomJS doesn't run in an Azure Web Job?

Comment: @miracledev I tried it like yagopv in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914676/headless-browsers-and-windows-azure-websites but PhantomJS just hangs after Process.Start(). It would be so great if it would run in an Azure Web Job.

Comment: As far as i remember it used to be the case that it didn't work because GDI wasnt supported but it is now, however there might be some limitations if you are on the free/shared tiers with your website. Maybe try out if it works on a Basic one?

Comment: I am already switched to the standard tier without success.